# Can "minor conjuration" create a 50 ft rope?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard

As a DM I have just been asked this:
"Can a coiled rope count if it's in the 3 ft cube?"

Honestly I applaud the initiative, but I can't find a definitive answer.
I have looked and I cannot find a suitable ruling.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @RBarryYoung 50 ft hemp rope weighs 10 lbs, 50 ft silk rope weighs 5 lbs

Answer (score 14):

### An argument could be made either way, but what's reasonable?

Technically speaking, a fifty foot length of rope is fifty feet long regardless of how it's coiled, and if you allow creating arbitrarily large objects as long as they can fold into a three foot volume, that could be potentially abused.

That said, there's absolutely nothing abusive about creating a simple adventuring item worth one gold piece, and most players would find this argument absurd.

And the players would be right: Being highly technical about what "no larger than 3 feet on a side" means is not going to make the game more fun for anyone. I would recommend being lenient in the interpretation of minor conjuration unless and until you have a specific reason not to be.

Comment: How would you rule on something like a knit hat? It could be argued it is just a special way to coil a long string. 

Could they conjure a 3'x3' knit blanket made with the desired material and unknit it?

Comment: With no minimum size defined one could create a black hole by conjuring something weighing 10 pounds in an infinitely small space. Which would probably be on the less reasonable side of things

Comment: @182764125216 I have no problem with a coiled rope *or* a knit cap.  Still, this is a good example of the argument ad absurdum.

Comment: @SirDuckduck What is this "black hole" of which you speak? This is D&D, not physics class.  (Anyway a 10-lb black hole would disintegrate from Hawking radiation in a microsecond.)

Comment: I'd love the implications of summoning a space-filling curve of infinitesimally thin thread. Need 3 kilometers of fishing line? Just fold them into a 3ft cube

Comment: Why not?  I'd allow it.  You have one hour to do what you need to do.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: *booom* Nice bomb.

Comment: @Joshua What, you mean the evaporating micro black hole?  Yes, that would represent the total conversion of 10 lbs of matter into energy in much less than a microsecond, which is equivalent to a perfectly efficient bomb containing five pounds of antimatter.  You'd have an explosion equivalent to a mid-range thermonuclear weapon with a casting range of 10 feet. If black holes existed in D&D, you could do this *once*.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym Ok now you've got me wondering if you could cast the spell on a timer and gate to another dimension before it goes off...

Comment: @Michael Minor Conjuration isn't a spell, it's a class ability for the Conjurer Wizard. So most shenanigans (symbol, glyph, contengency, metamagic, etc) aren't accessible.

Comment: Still you couldn't really create a micro black hole because "its form must be that of a nonmagical object that you have seen", and A) your wizard has never seen a black hole, and B) you can't see a microscopic black hole with a lifespan measured in microseconds that would kill you if you were anywhere near it when it comes into existence, sooooo

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: And that's why my sequence uses neutron star matter instead, for two thousand times less punch, but still more than enough for any reasonable use case.

Answer (score 10):

### You as the DM can decide how you handle this

The Minor Conjuration feature (p. 116 pHB) says:

> You can use your action to conjure up an inanimate object
> in your hand or on the ground in an unoccupied space that you can see within 10 feet of you. This object can be no larger than 3 feet on a side and weigh no more than 10 pounds, and its form must be that of a nonmagical object that you have seen.

It does not define a 3-foot cube anywhere. It is only talking about the object, and how long it is on each side.

You could argue a rope really does not have clearly defined sides -- it is flexible and if it is coiled up, it is an object that is no longer than 3 feet on each side. Or you could argue that the uncoiled rope with its maximum dimensions is what you should look at, [as in Thomas answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/199275/timeline).

So, you as the DM can decide how you want to rule this. In my view, conjuring up a 50-foot rope does not seem to be game breaking in any way, and may be fun and useful.

It's also hard to see a way this could be unfairly exploited, as it needs to be a single object they have seen before, and there also is a weight limit. Something like a tent that is folded up would violate both (and still is fine power-wise). If they spliced  together a couple of 50' ropes to make a 500' one, that would still fit, but fall afoul of the weight limit.

Answer (score 5):

#### The PC can conjure a coiled rope, but it might disappear if uncoiled

> This object can be no larger than 3 feet on a side

What does 'on a side' mean for an object?  The phrase is used all of four other times in the PHB, three times for spells or abilities that refer to an area of space, not an object (*shape the flowing river, control water, move earth*), once for the dimensions of a *forcecage*, and once for the *minor conjuration* itself.  Thus we don't have a lot to draw on when considering what the side of an object refers to, particularly a flexible object like a rope.

It is pretty easy to determine the side of an idealized shape, but the side of an actual object is much harder.  For example, [you might say](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/199275/23547) that a 50' length of rope is meant to be measured along its length, so that it has a 50' side even when it is coiled up.  But is this really the length of its side?  No actual rope is a flat cylinder, even when taut - it will have the ridges and valleys of its individual fibres, so do we measure along those?  The [coastline paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coastline_paradox) tells us that the smaller the unit we use to measure the surface of the rope, the longer the side of the rope will 'be'.  What if your player asks for a [Koch snowflake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) made of iron that fits in their hand?  Such an object could be tiny, and yet have a "side" that is far larger than 3 feet (it would, in fact, be infinite).

As the DM, you are welcome to make things hard on yourself (by creating an arbitrary standard for how you will measure the side of an object) - but in my experience, my games are more enjoyable for both myself and my players when I make such decisions as simple as possible.  The majority of the uses of 'on a side' in the PHB refer to area, so it is just simpler to rule that *minor conjuration* permits any object that fits in a three foot cube of space (as your player asked for) rather than worrying about how to measure the dimensions of the object itself.

Now, if you have particularly clever or inventive players, they might try to figure out how to abuse this ruling (although, as [Darth Pseudonym](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/199279/23547) says, it is hard to think of ways to abuse an item that is on the basic equipment list anyway).  If you think that permitting objects within a defined volume might lead to abuse of the kinds of objects they are creating, you have two outs: they can create a *coil* of rope, but if they then try to uncoil it, it becomes a *length* of rope, and runs afoul of the feature's injunction that it "can be no larger than 3 feet on a side".  Thus if they uncoil it sufficiently it will cease to exist.  Or, if they create something hard but malleable (like a block of silver or copper) and start to change its shape too much, you can say that they have "damaged" it and thus ended the effect.

Comment: +1 for a much more thorough exploration on what it means to talk about a "side" of an object

Comment: The "hard and malleable" object could be considered to have taken damage when deformed, as a justification for having it stop existing.  *The object disappears after 1 hour, when you use this feature again, or if it takes or deals any damage.*  That doesn't work for a rope, so I don't think it *should* disappear when uncoiled, if you allow it to be created in the first place.

Comment: @PeterCordes The uncoiling might make it disappear depending on what "This object can be no larger than 3 feet on a side" means.  Is that the condition for conjuring it to begin with, and later it can be changed - or is altering to the point when that is no longer true sufficient to dismiss it?  DM's call, and so a convenient excuse to get rid of it if desired.

Comment: I find it much more sensible for that condition to apply only when the ability is used.  It doesn't take your concentration to sustain it or anything, although it is made of magic.  Still, it has conditions listed for it disappearing, and changing shape isn't one of them.  I agree you could bend the wording this way if you really wanted to use that justification to impose the limitation, but it feels silly to me, for lack of a better word.

Comment: I find Thomas Markov's justification much more sensible if you want to disallow a rope. (For the coastline paradox, a measurement scale on the order magnitude of the diameter of the rope feels appropriate).  Then you could arguably still allow a 3x3 box with a lid that can open, since you're not elongating the object, just making part of it discontiguous (and bending part of it, the part of the lid above the hinges.)

Answer (score 3):

#### A 50 foot rope is 50 feet on a side.

Minor Conjuration states:

> This object can be no larger than 3 feet on a side

However, a 50 foot rope is 50 feet on a side, so it cannot be created with Minor Conjuration. The restriction here is not “fits within a 3 foot cube”, rather the restriction specifically calls out the dimensions of the object. So it doesn’t matter if the rope can be stuffed into a 3 foot cube, it is still 50 feet on a side.